# Including reference URL in bibliography using BibDesk

Tags: citing, source

I'm including several articles I found on f.e. ScienceDirect into BibDesk so I can reference them in my LaTeX file. (I'm using apacite in my LaTeX file but I don't think that matters right now). 
I'm trying to cite using APA-style file format so the link where I found my sources should be included in my bibliography.
When I go into BibDesk and I select the article option, I can enter all the information concerning my source, but I can't input my URL as to where I found the source online. Is there any way to include this link somewhere so it also appears in the bibliography in my LaTeX project?

Comment: Many modern styles support a `url` field where you just type in the URL in verbatim (without escaping any special characters). But some older styles may not support a dedicated field, then people usually use `note`. I don't know whether BibDesk shows the `url` field for `@article`s, but if it does not, you should either try to convince it to show the field or use a different tool that shows the field.

Comment: @moewe : Thanks. I looked in the BibDesk settings and there is an option to create a `url`field. Not sure if LaTeX or apacite is going to know it has to add the `url` + `Retrieved from: ` in front of the `url` to each of the different references. I'll have to figure that out as well.